# JPA and deprecated getOne() and getById() -> how to catch EntityNotFoundException in getReferenceById

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

In other similar questions on how to catch `EntityNotFoundException` the main tip was to use simpler methods that return null like `getOne`

As of spring-boot v 2.7 + both `getOne()` and `getById()` are marked as deprecated and documentation says to use `getReferenceById` instead.

The Problem as mentioned in some other question, that you can't simply catch `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`.

This is never be caught:

```kotlin
fun getDonation(donationId: Long): DonationDto? {
  return try {
    val entity: DonationEntity = donationJpaRepository.getById(donationId)
    mapper.toDonationDto(entity)
  } catch (e : EntityNotFoundException) {
    null
  }
}
```

Apart from downgrading the version and moving on with my life, how do I get to catch the exception or handle not found entities?

Answer (score 1):

You can only love the javadoc of `JpaRepository.getReferenceById(ID id)`

> Depending on how the JPA persistence provider is implemented this is very likely to always return an instance and throw an EntityNotFoundException on first access. Some of them will reject invalid identifiers immediately.

If you care about your mental health, use `CrudRepository.findById()` which guarantees that an empty optional will be returned if it cannot find the entity. Or better, just use the `EntityManager` and throw away the leaky abstraction of spring jpa.

If you need to load more than one entity, catching that expection might not give enough information to the client about what entity failed to be loaded. I know that in this case it's just one entity, but you'll probably have scenarios where you need to load more than one entity and having a consistent approach helps to maintain the code in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can catch
`JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException` in this case.

From the documentation to `JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException`

> JPA-specific subclass of ObjectRetrievalFailureException. Converts JPA's EntityNotFoundException.

```kotlin
return try {
   val dto = service.getStuff(id)
   ResponseEntity(dto, HttpStatus.OK)
} catch (e: JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException) {
   ResponseEntity("Nothing with id $id.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from downgrading the version and moving on with my life, how do I get to catch the exception or handle not found entities?

Apparently what you can do is trigger the entity proxy (returned by getReferenceById) to throw the EntityNotFoundException when it doesn't exist by accessing a property to trigger the loading of the actual entity.

For example:

```
fun getDonation(donationId: Long): DonationDto? {
    return try {
        val entityProxy: DonationEntity = donationJpaRepository.getReferenceById(donationId)
        // Accessing a property to trigger the loading of the actual entity
        entityProxy.id 
        mapper.toDonationDto(entityProxy)
    } catch (e: EntityNotFoundException) {
        // Handle the case where the entity is not found
        null
    }
}
```